# How expand a regex for one unit measure to match "unit x unit x unit" measure too?

Tags: regex

For text cleaning purposes, I have created a small regex to match numbers followed by measure units (used in Brazil):

```
^\d{1,2},\d{1,2}(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/i4rxS2/1/

But I don't know how expand it to match:

```
1,3x1,0x0,7cm
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Specification for your expanded version is unclear, but `^\d{1,2},(?:\dx\d,){0,2}\d{1,2}(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$` or `^\d{1,2},(?:\dx\d,){2}?\d{1,2}(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$` naively works on your case. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Possibly `^\d*,(\d*([x]\d*)?,)*\d*(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$`? This adds `(\d*([x]\d*)?,)` which will match 0 or more [digit(s), then an `x`, then digits]

Comment: Is [`^(\d\d?,\d\d?(?:c?m[²2]?|kg)?)(?:x(?1))*$`](https://regex101.com/r/i4rxS2/2) maybe usefull?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the shortest answer:

```
^(\d{1,2},?x?)+(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
^\d{1,2},\d{1,2}(x\d{1,2},\d{1,2}){,2}(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Optionally match a format for the added `1,3x1,0x` and you might shorten the alternation `(²|2)` to a character class `[²2]` matching 1 of the listed characters.

```
^\d{1,2},\d{1,2}(?:(?:x\d{1,2},\d{1,2}){2})?(?:cm|m[²2]?|kg)$
```

The pattern matches

- `^` Start of string
- `\d{1,2},\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits `,` and 1-2 digits
- `(?:(?:x\d{1,2},\d{1,2}){2})?` Optionally match the extra `1,3x1,0x` pattern
- `(?:cm|m[²2]?|kg)` Non capture group to match one of the alternatives
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mI7jP5/1)

It is not in the example data, but using `\d{1,2},\d{1,2}` does not match if there is no decimal part in for example `2kg`. In that case, you could make that part optional using `\d{1,2}(?:\,\d{1,2})?`

Answer (score 0):

Your initial regular expression assumes that *all* numbers are followed by a unit. That's not the case in multidimensional measurements, where an entire "set" of numbers is followed by a single unit. (We'll ignore the fact that `XxYxZcm` is a dubious abbreviation for `XcmxYcmxZcm`.)

Further, I would omit the `^` and `$` from the regular expression for measurements, and add them only when you are finally matching against a string.

```
>>> import re
>>> number = r'\d{1,2},\d{1,2}'
>>> unit = r'(cm|m(²|2)?|kg)'
>>> measurement = f'({number})(x({number}))*{unit}'
>>> re.match(rf'^{measurement}$', "1,3cm")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='1,3cm'>
>>> re.match(rf'^{measurement}$', "1,3x1,0x0,7cm")
<re.Match object; span=(0, 13), match='1,3x1,0x0,7cm'>
```